# How to implement a RabbitMQ consumer using Pyspark Streaming module?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pyspark, spark-streaming, pika

I have an Apache Spark cluster and a RabbitMQ broker and I want to consume messages and compute some metrics using the `pyspark.streaming` module.

The problem is I only found [this package](https://github.com/Stratio/Spark-RabbitMQ), but is implemented in *Java* and *Scala*. Besides that, I didn't find any example or bridge implementation in *Python*.

I have a consumer implemented using [Pika](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/0.10.0/) but I don't know how to pass the payload to my `StreamingContext`.

Comment: Well, I just discover that [Pyspark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.streaming.html#module-pyspark.streaming.mqtt) and [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/mqtt.html) both speak **MQTT protocol**. This could be a solution, but they are some trade-offs and limitations

Comment: To use the MQTT protocol on the RabbitMQ cluster implies to change the queue configurations. For me this is not a solution. I found a way to solve it. Once I complete my tests I'll post a solution

Comment: Hey, any progress? I'm facing the same problem now. In my case I cannot even setup MQTT proof of concept.

Comment: Yes, it was easier than I thought. I send my messages from my pika consumer to spark using a **TCP connection**. I will post a formal answer in few hours

Comment: Thx! I'm stuck here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39331781/spark-streaming-from-mqtt-illegalargumentexception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution uses [pika asynchronous consumer example](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/0.10.0/examples/asynchronous_consumer_example.html) and `socketTextStream` method from *Spark Streaming*

1. Download the example and save it as a `.py` file
2. Modify the file to use your own RabbitMQ credentials and connection parameters. In my case I had to modify the `Consumer` class
3. Under `if __name__ == '__main__':` we need to open a socket with the `HOST` and `PORT` corresponding to your TCP connection to Spark Streaming. We must save the method `sendall` from socket into a variable pass this to  the `Consumer` class

   ```
   with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
     s.bind((HOST, PORT))
     s.listen(1)
     conn, addr = s.accept()
     dispatcher = conn.sendall #assigning sendall to dispatcher variable
   consumer = Consumer(dispatcher)
   try:
     consumer.run()
   except Exception as e:
     consumer.stop()
     s.close()
   ```
4. Modify the `__init__` method in Consumer to pass the `dispatcher`

   ```
   def __init__(self,dispatcher):
     self._connection = None
     self._channel = None
     self._closing = False
     self._consumer_tag = None
     self._url = amqp_url
     #new code
     self._dispatcher = dispatcher
   ```
5. In the method `on_message` inside the Consumer we call `self._dispatcher` to send the `body` of the AMQP message

   ```
   def on_message(self, unused_channel, basic_deliver, properties, body):
     self._channel.basic_ack(basic_deliver.delivery_tag)
     try:
       # we need an '\n' at the each row Spark socketTextStream
       self._dispatcher(bytes(body.decode("utf-8")+'\n',"utf-8"))
     except Exception as e:
       raise
   ```
6. In Spark, put `ssc.socketTextStream(HOST, int(PORT))` with `HOST` and `PORT` corresponding to our TCP socket. Spark will manage the connection
7. **Run first the consumer and then the Spark application**

Final remarks:

- Try to run your consumer on a different machine rather than your Spark machine
- Any port over 10000 should be ok. Don't let the kernel to open some random port
- Platform: Linux Debian 7 and 8, and Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04
- Pika version 0.10.0
- Python version 3.5.2
- Spark version 1.6.1, 1.6.2, and 2.0.0

Comment: can you please provide me some guideline on how i can publish a message to rabbitmq using pyspark. To be specific I am using Azure Databricks and i am trying to publish a message to rabbitmq but couldn't figure out how I can achieve the same

Comment: Is there any requirements with the EXCHANGE and EXCHANGE_KEY arguments, or I can set it at will ? (EXCHANGE='', EXCHANGE_KEY='topic' ?)

Comment: `Channel 1 was closed: (Stream connection lost: TypeError('exchange must be a str or unicode str, but got <bound method RabbitConsumer.on_exchange_declareok of <RabbitConsumer object at 0x7f996653c3c8>>',))`.
I got this error, my Rabbitmq connection parameters are as follow: 
    EXCHANGE = 'message',
    EXCHANGE_TYPE = 'topic',
    QUEUE = 'item',
    ROUTING_KEY = 'item'.
I have a queue running 'item' with routing_key 'item'. When I tried your solution the above error popped up. Please help !